# DifR : Error in rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: r

I am using `difR` to perform a differential item functioning analysis on 3 groups.

Here is my code :

```
res<-difGenLord(Mat,group="Group",focal.names="2,3",nrFocal=2,model="1PL")
    Error in rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE) : 
    'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Which i dont understand because :

```
is.array(Mat)
[1] TRUE
> dim(Mat)
[1] 145 111
```

I must fundamentally understand something wrong in this... Can someone enlight me? Thanks in advance

ps: the traceback looks like this :

```
> traceback()
9: stop("'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions")
8: rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE)
7: as.vector(rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE))
6: start.val.rasch(start.val, X)
5: rasch(data, constraint = const)
4: itemPar1PL(data, engine = engine, discr = discr)
3: itemParEst(d0, model = "1PL", engine = engine, discr = discr)
2: internalGLord()
1: difGenLord(Mat, group = "Group", focal.names = "1,3", nrFocal = 2, 
       model = "1PL")
```

I know that similar errors have been already reported but the solution given did not help me yet.

Comment: show `str(Mat)`

Comment: Please post a small reproducible example

Comment: You may need to check the example in `?difGenLord` and its structure with your data

Comment: @Adamm    `str(Mat)
     num [1:145, 1:111] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:111] "Group" "Rose" "Untertasse" "Geweih" ...`

Comment: Indeed as akrun said, there's something wrong with your data - dimensions - in cimparison to the default input for this function.

Comment: @akrun @Adamm
Here is a small part of my data :
There are 3 Groups (3 different nationalities) and then items you can succeed (1) or fail (0) to name properly.

    `Group Rose Untertasse Geweih 
  [1,]     1    1          1      1       
  [2,]     1    1          1      1         
  [3,]     1    1          1      1      
  [4,]     2    1          1      1       
  [5,]     2    1          1      1       
  [7,]     3    1          1      1        
  [8,]     3    1          0      1        
  [9,]     3    1          1      1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not specify the "focal.names" correct. Try:

```
res<-difGenLord(Mat,group="Group",focal.names=c(2,3), model="1PL")
```